# Maclaurin Series for Implicit Differentiation

Tags: taylor-expansion, implicit-differentiation

[image]

I honestly tried, but I could not wrap my head around what they mean by 'Maclaurin series for y'; much less how they found y considering the only other information given was:

[image]

I first used integration, but then... am I supposed to substitute all values for y with 0 in order to obtain the maclaurin series? idk, it all seemed quite foreign to be. Help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's given $y=1$ when $x=0$, we have
$$y(x)=y(0)+y'(0)x+\frac{1}{2}y''(0)x^2 + ...$$
$$=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+....$$